# How can I skip dollar signs when creating snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Imagine I have this VSCode snippet:

```
    "Crear nueva función de AngujarJS": {
     "prefix": "AJSfunction",
     "body": [
         "$scope.${1:miFuncion} = function () {",
         "$2",
         "};"
      ],
     "description": "Crear nueva función en angular JS."
}
```

I have a static variable $scope, but I don't want the editor to stop in that point. How can I make VSCode skip that part? I only want VSCode to stop in `${1:miFuncion}` and `$2`

Comment: Do you want $scope printed as is?  If so, escape the $ like so \\$

Comment: @Mark not working :s

Answer (score 1):

```
"Crear nueva función de AngujarJS": {
   "prefix": "AJSfunction",
   "body": [
       "\\$scope.${1:miFuncion} = function () {",
       "$2",
       "};"         
   ],
   "description": "Crear nueva función en angular JS."
},
```

Note the double-escaped `\\$scope`, that is no longer a tabstop.

[image: demo]